# Flutter unable to catch PlatformException

Tags: flutter, error-handling, firebase-authentication

Error should supposed to show in the actual flutter code, but in my case errors are showing in the message_codec flies as show in the below figure, its getting hard to fine actual error in the code.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD24Q.jpg)

Comment: Fixed the issue..Just  need to uncheck the "All Exceptions and Uncaught Exception " which is located at the bottom left debug side bar(Breakppoints) in VS code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you have solved the issue and not waiting for an answer then please delete the question or answer by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue..Just need to uncheck the "All Exceptions and Uncaught Exception " which is located at the bottom left debug side bar(Breakppoints) in VS code